# My IOS app to monitor usage of other installed apps

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, swift, security

If you use an MDM, you can know and control a lot of things in IOS devices like which apps are running right now, blocking them, installing other apps, Battaery level etc.

However, I would like to have a feature in my IOS app, to tell me which apps are running in x IOS device while the user is using my app? In other words, Imagine the user is doing an exam in my app, I don't want the user to open Google app and search for answers on the device. For sure, this feature will be used by the permissions of the user. Is this possible? Do I need to develop an MDM for that?

Thanks!

Comment: Without going into *why* you would want such a thing (you asked us to "imagine"), well, **why** are you asking this? MDM is something private to the actual owners of the devices. In an MDM environment, the provider of those actual devices are employers. It sounds like you wish to get around things that are basic to iOS. Why not simply bypass the App Store and tell your target audience to jailbreak their app? Please, be at least a bit more specific about what you want!

Comment: If your use case is specifically for an exam then you can apply for an entitlement that allows your app to use the [Automatic Assessment Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/automaticassessmentconfiguration) but you can't create a general app that monitors or limits activity.

Answer (score 0):

Monitoring what other apps are running on iOS isn't possible because of the limitations of [the sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AboutAppSandbox/AboutAppSandbox.html). However, this was kind of possible before by querying what custom URL schemes an iOS app could open (`UIApplication`'s `canOpenURL`) but Apple closed that loophole a while back. A lot of advertising networks were abusing it.

Curiously, what you're asking for is 100% supported on macOS with `NSWorkspace`'s `runningApplications` but you have to disable the sandbox capability for this API to work properly.